# How I paginate a HTML table?

Tags: javascript, html, css, html-table, pagination

recently I am making Japanese vocaburaly sheet for studying it. I reference pagination code from [here](https://www.codeply.com/go/bp/lxa0FF9yhw), but for some reason, the pagination is not working. I have Css file, but I only wrote font and color formatting there, so i'm assuming that there something wrong with .js, but I don't know why.
Can somebody help with this code? Thank you for reading this.

```
<head>
    <script>
        $.fn.pageMe = function(opts){
    var $this = this,
        defaults = {
            perPage: 7,
            showPrevNext: false,
            hidePageNumbers: false
        },
        settings = $.extend(defaults, opts);
    
    var listElement = $this;
    var perPage = settings.perPage; 
    var children = listElement.children();
    var pager = $('.pager');
    
    if (typeof settings.childSelector!="undefined") {
        children = listElement.find(settings.childSelector);
    }
    
    if (typeof settings.pagerSelector!="undefined") {
        pager = $(settings.pagerSelector);
    }
    
    var numItems = children.size();
    var numPages = Math.ceil(numItems/perPage);

    pager.data("curr",0);
    
    if (settings.showPrevNext){
        $('<li><a href="#" class="prev_link">«</a></li>').appendTo(pager);
    }
    
    var curr = 0;
    while(numPages > curr && (settings.hidePageNumbers==false)){
        $('<li><a href="#" class="page_link">'+(curr+1)+'</a></li>').appendTo(pager);
        curr++;
    }
    
    if (settings.showPrevNext){
        $('<li><a href="#" class="next_link">»</a></li>').appendTo(pager);
    }
    
    pager.find('.page_link:first').addClass('active');
    pager.find('.prev_link').hide();
    if (numPages<=1) {
        pager.find('.next_link').hide();
    }
    pager.children().eq(1).addClass("active");
    
    children.hide();
    children.slice(0, perPage).show();
    
    pager.find('li .page_link').click(function(){
        var clickedPage = $(this).html().valueOf()-1;
        goTo(clickedPage,perPage);
        return false;
    });
    pager.find('li .prev_link').click(function(){
        previous();
        return false;
    });
    pager.find('li .next_link').click(function(){
        next();
        return false;
    });
    
    function previous(){
        var goToPage = parseInt(pager.data("curr")) - 1;
        goTo(goToPage);
    }
     
    function next(){
        goToPage = parseInt(pager.data("curr")) + 1;
        goTo(goToPage);
    }
    
    function goTo(page){
        var startAt = page * perPage,
            endOn = startAt + perPage;
        
        children.css('display','none').slice(startAt, endOn).show();
        
        if (page>=1) {
            pager.find('.prev_link').show();
        }
        else {
            pager.find('.prev_link').hide();
        }
        
        if (page<(numPages-1)) {
            pager.find('.next_link').show();
        }
        else {
            pager.find('.next_link').hide();
        }
        
        pager.data("curr",page);
        pager.children().removeClass("active");
        pager.children().eq(page+1).addClass("active");
    
    }
};

$(document).ready(function(){
    
  $('#myTable').pageMe({pagerSelector:'#myPager',showPrevNext:true,hidePageNumbers:false,perPage:4});
    
});
    </script>
    <link href="./css/mystyle.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>

<body>
    <div class="table-responsive" align=center>

        <table id="table table-hover" class="t-line" border=0 cellpadding=0 cellspacing=0 width=1311 border-collapse:
            collapse;table-layout:fixed;width:983pt>
            <col class=xl8620764>
            <col class=xl6720764 width=115 3908;>
            <col class=xl6620764 width=149 5085;>
            <col class=xl8620764 width=136 4642;>
            <col class=xl7720764 width=148 5034;>
            <col class=xl7520764 width=112 3805;>
            <col class=xl6520764 width=303 10342;>
            <col class=xl7520764 width=310 10581;>
            <tr height=53 height:39.4pt>
                <td height=53 class=xl8820764 style="background-color: #A9D08E;">&nbsp;</td>
                <td class=xl8820764 width=115 style="background-color: #A9D08E;">&nbsp;</td>
                <td colspan=6 class=xtitle width=1158 width:869pt style="background-color: #A9D08E;">Japanese
                    Vocabulary 6000</td>
            </tr>
            <thead>
                <tr class=xl7320764 height=49>
                    <th height=49 class=xtable-header style="text-align: right; padding-right: 15px;">#</td>
                    <th class=xtable-header width=115>Vocab-expression</th>
                    <th class=xtable-header width=149>Vocab-furigana</th>
                    <th class=xtable-header width=136>Roma-ji</th>
                    <th class=xtable-header width=148>Vocab-meaning</th>
                    <th class=xtable-header width=112>Vocab-pos</th>
                    <th class=xtable-header width=303>Sentence-expression</th>
                    <th class=xtable-header width=310>Sentence-meaning</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody id="myTable">
                <tr height=22 height:18pt>
                    <td height=22 class=x001>1</td>
                    <td class=x002 width=115>ＪＲ</td>
                    <td class=x003 width=149>ＪＲ[じぇいあーる]</td>
                    <td class=x004 width=136>jieiaru</td>
                    <td class=x005 width=148>JR, Japan Railways</td>
                    <td class=x006 font-size:10.0pt>Noun</td>
                    <td class=x007 width=303>私は通勤にJRを使うんだ。</td>
                    <td class=x008 width=310>I
                        commute by JR.</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class=x001>2</td>
                    <td class=x002 width=115>ああいう</td>
                    <td class=x003 width=149>ああいう</td>
                    <td class=x004 width=136>aaiu</td>
                    <td class=x005 width=148>that kind of</td>
                    <td class=x006>Adverb</td>
                    <td class=x007 width=303>ああいううるさい人は苦手です。</td>
                    <td class=x008 width=310>I don't like loud people
                        like that.</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class=x001>3</td>
                    <td class=x002 width=115>アイス</td>
                    <td class=x003 width=149>アイス</td>
                    <td class=x004 width=136>aisu</td>
                    <td class=x005 width=148>popsicle, ice lolly</td>
                    <td class=x006 font-size:10.0pt>Noun</td>
                    <td class=x007 width=303>暑いのでアイスを食べました。</td>
                    <td class=x008 width=310>I ate
                        ice cream because it was hot.</td>
                </tr>
                <tr height=42 height:31.5pt>
                    <td height=42 class=x001 height:31.5pt;>4</td>
                    <td class=x002 width=115>アイスクリーム</td>
                    <td class=x003 width=149>アイスクリーム</td>
                    <td class=x004 width=136>aisukurimu</td>
                    <td class=x005 width=148>ice cream</td>
                    <td class=x006>Noun</td>
                    <td class=x007 width=303>弟はアイスクリームが大好きです。</td>
                    <td class=x008 width=310>My little brother loves ice
                        cream.</td>
                </tr>
                <tr height=42 height:31.5pt>
                    <td height=42 class=x001 height:31.5pt;>5</td>
                    <td class=x002 width=115>アイスコーヒー</td>
                    <td class=x003 width=149>アイスコーヒー</td>
                    <td class=x004 width=136>aisukohi</td>
                    <td class=x005 width=148>iced coffee</td>
                    <td class=x006 font-size:10.0pt>Noun</td>
                    <td class=x007 width=303>アイスコーヒーをください。</td>
                    <td class=x008 width=310>Ill
                        have an iced coffee please.</td>
                </tr>
                <tr height=40 height:30.0pt>
                    <td height=40 class=x001 height:30.0pt;>6</td>
                    <td class=x002 width=115>あいづち</td>
                    <td class=x003 width=149>あいづち</td>
                    <td class=x004 width=136>aizuchi</td>
                    <td class=x005 width=148>responsive sounds, chiming
                        in</td>
                    <td class=x006>Noun</td>
                    <td class=x007 width=303>彼の話に私はあいづちを打ったの。</td>
                    <td class=x008 width=310>I chimed in as he spoke.</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class=x001>7</td>
                    <td class=x002 width=115>アイデア</td>
                    <td class=x003 width=149>アイデア</td>
                    <td class=x004 width=136>aidea</td>
                    <td class=x005 width=148>idea</td>
                    <td class=x006 font-size:10.0pt>Noun</td>
                    <td class=x007 width=303>彼がいいアイデアを出したね。</td>
                    <td class=x008 width=310>He
                        came up with a good idea.</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class=x001>8</td>
                    <td class=x002 width=115>アイドル</td>
                    <td class=x003 width=149>アイドル</td>
                    <td class=x004 width=136>aidoru</td>
                    <td class=x005 width=148>idol, pop singer</td>
                    <td class=x006>Noun</td>
                    <td class=x007 width=303>彼女は若者のアイドルです。</td>
                    <td class=x008 width=310>She is a youth icon.</td>
                </tr>
                <tr height=38 height:28.5pt>
                    <td height=38 class=x001 height:28.5pt;>9</td>
                    <td class=x002 width=115>あいにく</td>
                    <td class=x003 width=149>あいにく</td>
                    <td class=x004 width=136>ainiku</td>
                    <td class=x005 width=148>unfortunately</td>
                    <td class=x006 font-size:10.0pt>Adverb</td>
                    <td class=x007 width=303>途中であいにく雨が降り出したの。</td>
                    <td class=x008 width=310>Unfortunately,
                        it began to rain on the way.</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class=x001>10</td>
                    <td class=x002 width=115>アイロン</td>
                    <td class=x003 width=149>アイロン</td>
                    <td class=x004 width=136>airon</td>
                    <td class=x005 width=148>iron</td>
                    <td class=x006>Noun</td>
                    <td class=x007 width=303>彼女はシャツにアイロンをかけた。</td>
                    <td class=x008 width=310>She ironed the shirt.</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class=x001>11</td>
                    <td class=x002 width=115>あえて</td>
                    <td class=x003 width=149>あえて</td>
                    <td class=x004 width=136>aete</td>
                    <td class=x005 width=148>boldly</td>
                    <td class=x006 font-size:10.0pt>Adverb</td>
                    <td class=x007 width=303>彼はあえて危険を冒したの。</td>
                    <td class=x008 width=310>He
                        dared to face danger.</td>
                </tr>
                <tr height=60 height:45.0pt>
                    <td height=60 class=x001 height:45.0pt;>12</td>
                    <td class=x002 width=115>あきれる</td>
                    <td class=x003 width=149>あきれる</td>
                    <td class=x004 width=136>akireru</td>
                    <td class=x005 width=148>be stunned in
                        disappointment or disbelief</td>
                    <td class=x006>Verb</td>
                    <td class=x007 width=303>彼の頑固さにはあきれました。</td>
                    <td class=x008 width=310>I was amazed at his
                        stubbornness.</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class=x001>13</td>
                    <td class=x002 width=115>アクセサリー</td>
                    <td class=x003 width=149>アクセサリー</td>
                    <td class=x004 width=136>akusesari</td>
                    <td class=x005 width=148>accessories, jewelry</td>
                    <td class=x006 font-size:10.0pt>Noun</td>
                    <td class=x007 width=303>このアクセサリーは素敵ね。</td>
                    <td class=x008 width=310>This
                        jewelry is lovely.</td>
                </tr>
                <tr height=42 height:31.5pt>
                    <td height=42 class=x001 height:31.5pt;>14</td>
                    <td class=x002 width=115>アクセント</td>
                    <td class=x003 width=149>アクセント</td>
                    <td class=x004 width=136>akusento</td>
                    <td class=x005 width=148>accent, stress</td>
                    <td class=x006>Noun</td>
                    <td class=x007 width=303>アメリカ英語とイギリス英語ではアクセントが違うことがあるね。</td>
                    <td class=x008 width=310>There can be a difference
                        in stress between American and British English.</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class=x001>15</td>
                    <td class=x002 width=115>あくび</td>
                    <td class=x003 width=149>あくび</td>
                    <td class=x004 width=136>akubi</td>
                    <td class=x005 width=148>yawn</td>
                    <td class=x006 font-size:10.0pt>Verbal Noun</td>
                    <td class=x007 width=303>父があくびをした。</td>
                    <td class=x008 width=310>My
                        father yawned.</td>
                </tr>
                <tr height=42 height:31.5pt>
                    <td height=42 class=x001 height:31.5pt;>16</td>
                    <td class=x002 width=115>あぐら</td>
                    <td class=x003 width=149>あぐら</td>
                    <td class=x004 width=136>agura</td>
                    <td class=x005 width=148>sit cross legged</td>
                    <td class=x006>Noun</td>
                    <td class=x007 width=303>彼はあぐらをかいてしゃべっていますね。</td>
                    <td class=x008 width=310>He is talking while sitting
                        cross-legged.</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class=x001>17</td>
                    <td class=x002 width=115>あげる</td>
                    <td class=x003 width=149>あげる</td>
                    <td class=x004 width=136>ageru</td>
                    <td class=x005 width=148>give</td>
                    <td class=x006 font-size:10.0pt>Verb</td>
                    <td class=x007 width=303>この本、あなたにあげます。</td>
                    <td class=x008 width=310>Ill
                        give you this book.</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class=x001>18</td>
                    <td class=x002 width=115>あそこ</td>
                    <td class=x003 width=149>あそこ</td>
                    <td class=x004 width=136>asoko</td>
                    <td class=x005 width=148>over there</td>
                    <td class=x006>Pronoun</td>
                    <td class=x007 width=303>あそこにバス停があります。</td>
                    <td class=x008 width=310>Theres a bus stop over
                        there.</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class=x001>19</td>
                    <td class=x002 width=115>あだな</td>
                    <td class=x003 width=149>あだな</td>
                    <td class=x004 width=136>adana</td>
                    <td class=x005 width=148>nickname</td>
                    <td class=x006 font-size:10.0pt>Noun</td>
                    <td class=x007 width=303>彼のあだなは「りき」です。</td>
                    <td class=x008 width=310>His
                        nickname is &quot;Ricky.&quot;</td>
                </tr>
                <tr height=38 height:28.5pt>
                    <td height=38 class=x001 height:28.5pt;>20</td>
                    <td class=x002 width=115>あちこち</td>
                    <td class=x003 width=149>あちこち</td>
                    <td class=x004 width=136>achikochi</td>
                    <td class=x005 width=148>all over</td>
                    <td class=x006>Noun</td>
                    <td class=x007 width=303>私たちは朝からあちこち散歩しました。</td>
                    <td class=x008 width=310>We strolled about here and
                        there from the morning.</td>
                </tr>
            <tbody>
        </table>

    </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: in order for this code to work you have to probably include JQuery either from CDN or from js file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I THINK YOU JUST MISSED TO INCLUDE BOOTSTRAP PLUGINS

<!@--CSS IN TOP HEADER-->

<@link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/normalize/8.0.1/normalize.min.css">
<@link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<!@--JS IN THE BOTTOM OF THE BODY-->

<@script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js">
<@script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js">

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<title>PAGINATION</title>
<base target="_self"> 

<!--BOOTSTRAP PLUGIN-->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/normalize/8.0.1/normalize.min.css">  
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<style>
.table-responsive {height:180px;}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
<div class="table-responsive">
<table class="table table-hover">
<thead>
<tr>
<th>#</th>
<th>Table heading</th>
<th>Table heading</th>
<th>Table heading</th>
<th>Table heading</th>
<th>Table heading</th>
<th>Table heading</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody id="myTable">
<tr style="display: table-row;">
<td>1</td>
<td>Table cell</td>
<td>Table cell</td>
<td>Table cell</td>
<td>Table cell</td>
<td>Table cell</td>
<td>Table cell</td>
</tr>
<tr style="display: table-row;">
<td>2</td>
<td>Table cell</td>
<td>Table cell</td>
<td>Table cell</td>
<td>Table cell</td>
<td>Table cell</td>
<td>Table cell</td>
</tr>
<tr style="display: table-row;">
<td>3</td>
<td>Table cell</td>
<td>Table cell</td>
<td>Table cell</td>
<td>Table cell</td>
<td>Table cell</td>
<td>Table cell</td>
</tr>
<tr style="display: table-row;">
<td>4</td>
<td>Table cell</td>
<td>Table cell</td>
<td>Table cell</td>
<td>Table cell</td>
<td>Table cell</td>
<td>Table cell</td>
</tr>
<tr class="success" style="display: none;">
<td>5</td>
<td>Table cell</td>
<td>Table cell</td>
<td>Table cell</td>
<td>Table cell</td>
<td>Table cell</td>
<td>Table cell</td>
</tr>
<tr style="display: none;">
<td>6</td>
<td>Table cell</td>
<td>Table cell</td>
<td>Table cell</td>
<td>Table cell</td>
<td>Table cell</td>
<td>Table cell</td>
</tr>
<tr style="display: none;">
<td>7</td>
<td>Table cell</td>
<td>Table cell</td>
<td>Table cell</td>
<td>Table cell</td>
<td>Table cell</td>
<td>Table cell</td>
</tr>
<tr style="display: none;">
<td>8</td>
<td>Table cell</td>
<td>Table cell</td>
<td>Table cell</td>
<td>Table cell</td>
<td>Table cell</td>
<td>Table cell</td>
</tr>
<tr style="display: none;">
<td>9</td>
<td>Table cell</td>
<td>Table cell</td>
<td>Table cell</td>
<td>Table cell</td>
<td>Table cell</td>
<td>Table cell</td>
</tr>
<tr style="display: none;">
<td>10</td>
<td>Table cell</td>
<td>Table cell</td>
<td>Table cell</td>
<td>Table cell</td>
<td>Table cell</td>
<td>Table cell</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>   
</div>
<div class="col-md-12 text-center">
<ul class="pagination pagination-lg pager" id="myPager"></ul>
</div>
</div>
</div>

<!--JAVASCRIPT-->
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script>
$.fn.pageMe = function(opts){
var $this = this,
defaults = {
perPage: 7,
showPrevNext: false,
hidePageNumbers: false
},
settings = $.extend(defaults, opts);

var listElement = $this;
var perPage = settings.perPage; 
var children = listElement.children();
var pager = $('.pager');

if (typeof settings.childSelector!="undefined") {
children = listElement.find(settings.childSelector);
}

if (typeof settings.pagerSelector!="undefined") {
pager = $(settings.pagerSelector);
}

var numItems = children.size();
var numPages = Math.ceil(numItems/perPage);

pager.data("curr",0);

if (settings.showPrevNext){
$('<li><a href="#" class="prev_link">«</a></li>').appendTo(pager);
}

var curr = 0;
while(numPages > curr && (settings.hidePageNumbers==false)){
$('<li><a href="#" class="page_link">'+(curr+1)+'</a></li>').appendTo(pager);
curr++;
}

if (settings.showPrevNext){
$('<li><a href="#" class="next_link">»</a></li>').appendTo(pager);
}

pager.find('.page_link:first').addClass('active');
pager.find('.prev_link').hide();
if (numPages<=1) {
pager.find('.next_link').hide();
}
pager.children().eq(1).addClass("active");

children.hide();
children.slice(0, perPage).show();

pager.find('li .page_link').click(function(){
var clickedPage = $(this).html().valueOf()-1;
goTo(clickedPage,perPage);
return false;
});
pager.find('li .prev_link').click(function(){
previous();
return false;
});
pager.find('li .next_link').click(function(){
next();
return false;
});

function previous(){
var goToPage = parseInt(pager.data("curr")) - 1;
goTo(goToPage);
}

function next(){
goToPage = parseInt(pager.data("curr")) + 1;
goTo(goToPage);
}

function goTo(page){
var startAt = page * perPage,
endOn = startAt + perPage;

children.css('display','none').slice(startAt, endOn).show();

if (page>=1) {
pager.find('.prev_link').show();
}
else {
pager.find('.prev_link').hide();
}

if (page<(numPages-1)) {
pager.find('.next_link').show();
}
else {
pager.find('.next_link').hide();
}

pager.data("curr",page);
pager.children().removeClass("active");
pager.children().eq(page+1).addClass("active");

}
};

$(document).ready(function(){

$('#myTable').pageMe({pagerSelector:'#myPager',showPrevNext:true,hidePageNumbers:false,perPage:4});

});
</script>
<script>
// prevent navigation
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
var links = document.getElementsByTagName("A");
for(var i=0; i < links.length; i++) {
links[i].addEventListener("click", function(e) {
var href = this.getAttribute("href")

if (!href) {
return
}

if (href === '#') {
// hash only ('#')
console.debug('Internal nav allowed by Codeply');
e.preventDefault()
}
else if (this.hash) {
// hash with tag ('#foo')
var element = null
try {
element = document.querySelector(this.hash)
}
catch(e) {
console.debug('Codeply internal nav querySelector failed')
}
if (element) {
// scroll to anchor
e.preventDefault();
const top = element.getBoundingClientRect().top + window.pageYOffset
//window.scrollTo({top, behavior: 'smooth'})
window.scrollTo(0,top)
console.debug('Internal anchor controlled by Codeply to element:' + this.hash)
}
else {
// allow javascript routing
console.debug('Internal nav route allowed by Codeply');
}
}
else if (href.indexOf("/p/")===0 || href.indexOf("/v/")===0) {
// special multi-page routing
console.debug('Special internal page route: ' + href)

var l = href.replace('/p/','/v/')

// reroute
e.preventDefault()
var newLoc = l + '?from=internal'
console.debug('Internal view will reroute to ' + newLoc) 
location.href = newLoc
}
else if (href.indexOf("./")===0) {
// special multi-page routing
console.debug('Special internal ./ route: ' + href)

var u = parent.document.URL.split("/")
var pn = href.split("/")[1]
var plyId = u[u.length-1]

if (plyId.indexOf('?from')>-1) {
// already rerouted this
console.debug('already rerouted')
plyId = u[u.length-2]
}

var l = plyId + '/' + pn

console.debug(u)
console.debug(pn)
console.debug('l',l)

// reroute
e.preventDefault()
var newLoc = '/v/' + l + '?from=internal'
console.debug('Internal page will reroute to ' + newLoc) 
location.href = newLoc
}
else {
// no external links
e.preventDefault();
console.debug('External nav prevented by Codeply');
}
//return false;
})
}
}, null);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```